# Is there a way to check if two class objects are the same type in python? (Not isinstance)

Tags: python

Lets say I have two objects here:

```
<test.object1 object at 0x103baasdfa0>, <test.object1 object at 0x103baasdfa1>
```

Is there a way to check if these two objects are referencing the same class object? I know isinstance works:

if isinstance(x, object1)

But I am trying to see if these two equal each other in the type of object

Comment: "if these two objects are referencing the same class object" what does it mean for two objects to "reference the same class object"? "I am trying to see if these two equal each other in the type of object" what do you mean by "equal" in this context?

Comment: `type(left) is type(right)` if you're trying to compare exact types without allowing subclasses.

Comment: *"referencing the same class object"*, or referencing **instances of** the same class?

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way, which doesn't consider subclass relationships (unlike `isintance` which does) is simply:

```
type(obj1) is type(obj2)
```

Alternatively, if you want something like "is either object the same type or a subclass of the other object", then more generally, you can use something like:

```
issubclass(type(obj1), type(obj2)) or issubclass(type(obj2), type(obj1))
```

Of course, you can use the more constrained alternative as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the `type` of one of the two, first:

```py
a: int = 123
b: str = "abc"
c: str = "def"

print(isinstance(a, type(c))) # => False
print(isinstance(b, type(c))) # => True
```